# Difference between + and +=

Tags: c#, casting

I Have:

```
Byte a = 100;
a = (Byte) a + 200;
```

OR

```
Byte a = 100;
a += 200;
```

In the first version I need a cast (because +operator returns int). But no cast needed in second expression allthough += returns int too.

Why is it that in the second example casting is done automatically?